# Core data - Set many-to-one relationship with NSBatchInsertRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entities, `User` and `Post`. A `User` contains many `Post`, and each `Post` has only one `User`.

I am trying to batch insert more than 1000 posts.

```
private func newBatchInsertRequest(with posts: [PostData]) -> NSBatchInsertRequest {
    var index = 0
    let total = posts.count
    let batchInsert = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: Post.entity()) { (managedObject: NSManagedObject) -> Bool in
        guard index < total else { return true }
        
        if let post = managedObject as? Post {
            let data = posts[index]
            post.createdData = data.createdDate
            post.identifier = data.identifier
            post.text = data.text
        }
        
        index += 1
        return false
    }
    
    PersistenceController.shared.container.performBackgroundTask { context in
        try? context.execute(batchInsert)
        try? context.save()
    }
}
```

It inserts all the posts that I want to insert. However, I can not configure how to set their `User`.

I tried to use the following code, but it did not work.

```
let updateRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entity: Post.entity())
updateRequest.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType
updateRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["user": user]

 try? context.execute(updateRequest)
```

I get the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid relationship ((<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x2801045a0>), name item, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Post, renamingIdentifier item
```

---

I can set their user one by one, but it is inefficient due to long processing time.

How to update the user property of Posts in a more efficient way?

---

#### Update

All of these posts belongs to one `User` which does not exist yet. I need to create it before or after executing the `NSBatchInsertRequest`.

`User` has three properties

```
   1. createdDate: Date
   2. identifier: UUID
   3. name: String
```

---

*My goal is to insert Post that belongs to one Use either using `NSBatchInsertRequest`  or in a private context so that it does not block the main  thread.*

Comment: It’s not clear how you identifies which user should be connected to a post?

Comment: Then why not create the user first and then assign it to the posts in newBatchInsertRequest?

Comment: They have different context. In core data, objects bounds to a context can not be used in another context. @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would try:

- Create the `User` before your batch operation. Yep, it's going to be on a different context — just make sure you grab its `NSManagedObjectID` (it's a property on `NSManagedObject`) and save it on a private property.
- Inside your `PersistenceController.shared.container.performBackgroundTask` you have a reference to your private context. Use the managed object ID from before to fetch/register the same `User` in your private context:

```
let user = context.object(with: userManagedObjectID)
```

- Then pass this user into the method that creates your batch insert request to set the user property on your `Post` objects.

I believe if you set up your inverse relationship up in the data model editor you don't need to populate `User.posts`. That should happen automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks. It does not work. I created a User before `PersistenceController.shared.container.performBackgroundTask` and assigned `context.object(with: userManagedObjectID)` to `post.user`. Got the this error: *'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship ‘u’ser between objects in different contexts*

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in different way.

1. In my entity which needs to have relationship added placeholder attributed tmpID.
2. When creating batch inserts setting tmpID to particular string. As example parent objectID **parent.objectID**.
3. Executing batch insert.
4. Then fetching all object from CoreData with tmpID.
5. Then going throw everyone and setting:

   1. Relationship
   2. tmpID to nil, the do not waist a memory.
6. Saving managed object context.

To merge I am using function:

```
/// Executes the given `NSBatchDeleteRequest` and directly merges the changes to bring the given managed object context up to date.
///
/// - Parameter batchDeleteRequest: The `NSBatchDeleteRequest` to execute.
/// - Throws: An error if anything went wrong executing the batch deletion.
public func executeAndMergeChanges(using batchDeleteRequest: NSBatchDeleteRequest) throws {
    batchDeleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs
    let result = try execute(batchDeleteRequest) as? NSBatchDeleteResult
    let changes: [AnyHashable: Any] = [NSDeletedObjectsKey: result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] ?? []]
    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes, into: [self])
}

// Use case:
        do {
            try container.viewContext.executeAndMergeChanges(using: deleteReqest)
            try container.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            Logger.app.e("Can not destroy/save clean table: \(name) -> \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: do you know how to make sure the context is refreshed after a batch insert? I've tried everything I know, and the objects I created using the batch insert do not exist in any contexts yet

Comment: @YichenBman I have added one function to my answer which merges changes.