# Any clean way for batch inserting coredata objects with relationships?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, concurrency

I have been observing high CPU times in background threads while inserting the coredata objects, and from analyser i could find that it's coming majorly because of some relationships i was creating one by one, and those could be in thousands.

So i thought if i could create them with batch insert. I can do that easily for objects using without relationships using [NSBatchInsertRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest/3333235-init), but with relationships, I can't seem to find any clean way.Without relationships, i can easily create dictionaries and insert using the above request.

​

With relationships, i also tried using the [object handler method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest/3618788-init) of NSBatchInsertRequest, but even that is giving me an exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'run' between objects in different contexts
```

---

This is how i am trying to make sure that the trackpoint getting added is using the run object from the same context as the one in which its being created

```
func addTrackPoints(run: RunModel, objectId: NSManagedObjectID) async throws {
        let locations:[CLLocation] = run.getLocations()
        let count = run.getLocations().count
        var index = 0
        let batchInsert = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: TrackPoint.entity()) { (managedObject: NSManagedObject) -> Bool in
          guard index < count  else { return true }
          if let trackPoint = managedObject as? TrackPoint {
              let data = locations[index]
              guard let run = try? StorageService.shared.getBackgroundContext().object(with: objectId) as? Run else {
                  fatalError("failed to get run object")
              }
              trackPoint.run = run
          }
          index += 1
          return false
        }

        try await StorageService.shared.batchInsert(entity: TrackPoint.entity(), batchInsertRequest: batchInsert, context: StorageService.shared.getBackgroundContext())
}
```

---

I also tried it without accessing the object from same context but instead tried directly using the Run object that i had created. It didn't crash, but it still didn't create the relationship.Also it forced me to remove the concurrencydebug run argument.

```
func addTrackPoints(run: RunModel, object: Run) async throws {
        let locations = run.getLocations()
        let count = run.getLocations().count
        var index = 0
        let batchInsert = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: TrackPoint.entity()) { (managedObject: NSManagedObject) -> Bool in
          guard index < count  else { return true }

          if let trackPoint = managedObject as? TrackPoint {
              let data:CLLocation = locations[index]
              trackPoint.run = object
          }
          index += 1
          return false
        }

        try await StorageService.shared.batchInsert(entity: TrackPoint.entity(), batchInsertRequest: batchInsert, context: StorageService.shared.getBackgroundContext()) }
```

---

*StorageService*

```
public func batchInsert(entity: NSEntityDescription, batchInsertRequest: NSBatchInsertRequest, context: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil) async throws {
        var taskContext:NSManagedObjectContext? = context
        if(taskContext == nil) {
            taskContext = StorageService.shared.newTaskContext()
            // Add name and author to identify source of persistent history changes.
            taskContext?.name = "importContext"
            taskContext?.transactionAuthor = "import\(entity.name ?? "entity")"
        }

        /// - Tag: performAndWait
        try await taskContext?.perform {
            // Execute the batch insert.
            do{
                let fetchResult = try taskContext?.execute(batchInsertRequest)
                if let batchInsertResult = fetchResult as? NSBatchInsertResult,
                   let success = batchInsertResult.result as? Bool, success {
                    return
                }
            } catch {
                self.logger.error("Failed to execute batch insert request. \(error)")
            }
            throw SSError.batchInsertError
        }

        logger.info("Successfully inserted data for \(entity.name ?? "entity")")
    }
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated :-)

Comment: show StorageService please )

Comment: Just curious, in your original code did were you saving after every insert statement? Is frequent save causing the issue? If so could you build all data (that can be grouped) and then save it once.

Comment: I usually just make the entities conform to Codable and pick a direction. It is hard to account for the 2-way relationship when decoding but if you stick to a single direction it makes it a simpler approach.

Comment: @StepanMaksymov added the storage service batch insert method too

Comment: @user1046037 not on every trackpoint, but it was happening for every run though. But I don't think that should be the because number of saves in that case would be hardly 30-40
However with this model, the number of saves comes to just 2

Comment: @loremipsum hi, in most of the coredata objects with relationships i have written the encoding/decoding logic, are you avoiding that too?

Comment: I written the `init` and `encode` methods but it only works from parent to child not from child to parent. In other words children don't create parent objects but parents can create child objects. You just have to pick one direction since saving only happens once. The whole thing happens on its own with a `JSONDecoder` `decoder` call.

Comment: Could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65523753/core-data-set-many-to-one-relationship-with-nsbatchinsertrequest Also try and use `.empty` vs `.count`. Just a heads for a stationary object CLLocation would return an array of locations, actually it only makes sense to pick one of them (first or last).

Comment: @user1046037 are you referring to this part where the user is first creating the posts in batch, then fetching and inserting - this looks unnecessary right? he should be able to insert the relationship while creating the object itself as long as the related object is ready.

In case you are referring to getting the object with that managed context, that i am already doing using StorageService.shared.getBackgroundContext().object(with: objectId)

Comment: Look on some workaround Below @Puneet

Answer (score -2):

How app works, I send request to server, get some results and want data to be saved in core data for further usage to send request to server only when needed. so next time I will query data from database.

Here is sample:

I always save data in background context, which is configured like this:

```
func getBgContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let bgContext = self.persistenceController.container.newBackgroundContext()
    bgContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    bgContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

    return bgContext
}
```

Next I construct my data models like this so decoder will handle entity creation and data parsing + insertion in dbContext:

```
public class SomeDataModel: NSManagedObject, Codable {
    var entityName: String = "SomeDataModel"

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case someData = "someData"
    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard
            let context = decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "SomeDataModel", in: context)
        else {
            throw DecoderConfigurationError.missingManagedObjectContext
        }

        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        id = try values.decode(Int32.self, forKey: .id)
        someData = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .someData)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(someData, forKey: .someData)
    }

    func toExternalModel() -> SomeExternalUsableModel {
        return SomeExternalUsableModel(id: id, someData: someData)
    }
}

extension SomeDataModel {
        @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SomeDataModel> {
            return NSFetchRequest<SomeDataModel>(entityName: "SomeDataModel")
        }
    
        @NSManaged public var someData: String?
        @NSManaged public var id: Int32
        
}
    
extension SomeDataModel: Identifiable {
}
```

to pass dbcontext to decoder I do next:

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
  static let managedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "managedObjectContext")!
}
```

dbContext - create background context somewhere in API helper class, and use this context for all the parsings below.

and next I do parsing with decoder when respond from server comes:

```
let model = try self.dbContext.performAndWait {
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    // pass context to decoder/encoder
    jsonDecoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext] = self.dbContext
    jsonEncoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext] = self.dbContext
    // parse model, used generic for reuse for other models 
    let model = try jsonDecoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
    // after this line - all the data is parsed from response from server, and saved to dbContext, and contained in model as well
    if self.dbContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try self.dbContext.save()
            self.dbContext.refreshAllObjects() // refresh context objects to ELIMINATE all outdated db objects in memory (specially when you will have relations, they could remain in memory until updated)
        } catch let error {
            // process error                   
        }
    }
    return model
}
// do with saved and ready to use data in models whatever needed:    
return model
```

and extensions used for performAndWait

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    func performAndWait<T>(_ block: () throws -> T) throws -> T? {
        var result: Result<T, Error>?
        performAndWait {
            result = Result { try block() }
        }
        return try result?.get()
    }

    func performAndWait<T>(_ block: () -> T) -> T? {
        var result: T?
        performAndWait {
            result = block()
        }
        return result
    }
}
```